# As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?

Tags: aplicação-web, gui, console, ux

É comum encontrar uma mensagem de erro que diz: "*Desculpe, você não tem permissão para acessar esta função. Entre em contato com o administrador para obter ajuda.*"

É apropriado um "pedido de desculpas" neste caso?

É um caso claro que o problema não é culpa do sistema/plataforma/provedor do serviço. Então por que deveria existir esse pedido de desculpas? Isso é importante?

Tem alguma fonte de informação autoritativa que justifique o seu uso?

Note que não estou perguntando se você usa de um jeito ou de outro, e o que você acha que é certo. **Respostas com opiniões sem base são inválidas e devem ser votadas negativamente**. Informações que indiquem com clareza e justificativa de qual o motivo do uso, ou não, são construtivas.

Comment: Mensagens de erro devem ser compreensivas para o usuário. Mais importante explicar de forma fácil para ele saber o que aconteceu, e verificar se o erro é dele ou do sitema, do que apenas receber um "Desculpe, ocorreu um erro".

Comment: O pessoal também entende de psicologia, minha humilde opinião dar desculpa é gentil, porém seria muito mais proveitoso dar a desculpa e informar uma link ou na própria mensagem os requisitos para alcançar aquela permissão, e se são alcançáveis. Algo como "Desculpe, sua reputação não permite tomar essa ação, conheça "aqui" como funciona e como conseguir essa reputação mínima"

Comment: De qualquer forma, as mensagens de erro devem ser claras, diferente de: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/378314 "Sorry, something went wrong. An unexpected error has ocurred."

Comment: Na minha humilde opinião, levando em consideração o cenário de uma aplicação que usa o HTTP, erros do tipo 4xx não devem pedir desculpas, afinal o erro do cliente, já os erros do tipo 5xx, sim, porque o erro é da aplicação, principalmente se essa for paga. De qualquer jeito, como já foi dito, a mesagem de erro deve ser clara e completa ou conter um link que explique melhor

Answer (score 220, accepted):

Essa questão é complexa e envolve, ao meu ver, dois aspectos principais:

- O contexto cultural no qual a interação humano-computador está inserida.
- O contexto de utilização (erro, alerta informativo, etc) que fez necessária a exibição da mensagem ao usuário.

**Sobre o contexto cultural...**

Primeiramente, há de se considerar que existem diferenças culturais significativas com relação ao ato de se desculpar. Há estudos comparando as culturas americana e japonesa que mostram que em certas situações (como, por exemplo, quando alguém recolhe uma caneta que você derrubou) americanos utilizam a palavra *thanks* (obrigado) para expressar gratidão enquanto que japoneses utilizam a palavra *sumimasen* (sinto muito) *para expressar um sentimento semelhante* - ainda que sob um significado cultural de humildade ou subjugação ([Sugimoto, Naomi. "Sorry we apologize so much": Linguistic Factors Affecting Japanese and U.S. American Styles of Apology. Intercultural Communication Studies VIII-1, 1998](http://www.uri.edu/iaics/content/1998v8n1/06%20Naomi%20Sugimoto.pdf)).

Eu procurei encontrar material semelhante comparando outras culturas com culturas latinas, mas não encontrei (talvez esses estudos ainda não sejam comuns por aqui). De todas as formas, por experiência própria eu acredito que essa mesma distinção também existe com relação à nossa cultura: tenho amigos ingleses e franceses que não têm o menor pudor em convidar apenas parte de um grupo para uma festa infantil (em frente aos demais, não convidados por não se encaixarem na condição "ter filhos"); nesse mesmo cenário, nós latinos faríamos o convite de forma individual e privada ou nos desculparíamos por não convidar os solteiros e os casais sem filhos.

O fato é que a desculpa é um lubrificante social importante, cujo caráter na interação serve também como forma de indicar a real intenção do interlocutor (algo como "eu realmente não quis te machucar/incomodar de propósito"), e por isso é tradicionalmente utilizada para iniciar uma conversação considerando uma possível interrupção de qualquer introspecção/atividade do destinatário da mensagem ([Wagatsuma, Hiroshi e Rosett, Arthur. "The Implications of Apology: Law and Culture in Japan and the United States". Law & Society Review, v.20, n.4, 1986](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3053463?uid=3737664&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21103419047523)). Especialmente em relação à cultura japonesa, o pedido de desculpa é considerado como necessário para "preparar a atmosfera" da interação (["Why Japanese apologize so often?", Facebook Note - Japanese Language & Culture, 2008](https://www.facebook.com/notes/japanese-language-culture/why-japanese-apologize-so-often/41402121768)), mas novamente eu acredito que isso também se passa na cultura latina quando iniciamos uma conversação ("desculpe senhor, que horas são?" não necessariamente indica uma falha ou culpa, e tem para nós praticamente o mesmo significado de "com licença senhor, que horas são?").

**Sobre o contexto de utilização...**

Além do contexto cultural, há de se considerar também que a apresentação da mensagem tem por objetivo comunicar ao usuário (leia-se "o homem") alguma informação **relevante** da condição em que a aplicação (leia-se "o computador") se encontra. Em outras palavras, trata-se de uma interação humano-computador iniciada pelo computador. Há pouco mais de 10 anos os cientistas da computação se interessam por pesquisas relacionadas à [Experiência de Usuário](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experi%C3%AAncia_do_usu%C3%A1rio) e à [Computação Afetiva](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_afetiva), e cada vez mais se acredita que o caráter hedônico, emocional e social da interação é fundamental não apenas na escolha de um produto como também na continuidade de sua utilização. Isso quer dizer que não basta um produto ser seguro, eficaz e agradável (no sentido de ausência de desconforto), ele também deve prover uma experiência interessante e apropriada ao contexto em que é utilizado.

Lembro-me do *key note* apresentado pela profa. Dra. [Soraia Raupp Musse](http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~smusse/) no [WVC'2008](http://www2.fc.unesp.br/wvc2008/PalestraSoraia.php) em que ela citou o exemplo de uma das primeiras sessões do filme ["O Expresso Polar"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338348/) apresentada para uma plateia de crianças. Segundo a professora, a forma como os olhos dos personagens se moviam em uma determinada cena (não lembro qual especificamente) era tão distinta do natural que muitas das crianças pequenas simplesmente choraram de medo. Esse exemplo é um tanto exagerado aqui, mas serve para ilustrar o ponto em que quero chegar: a forma como a interação ocorre é importante para a parte humana dessa interação, pois é natural que nós busquemos humanizar o outro lado (isto é, a máquina).

Há inúmeros trabalhos sendo realizados para construir agentes computacionais humanoides com o objetivo de tornar a interação mais empática por meio da mimetização de expressões faciais e corpóreas, e também de expressões vocais como o "hum hum" que denota "estou te entendendo" (exemplos [1](http://magalie.ochs.free.fr/Empathic%20Dialog%20Agent%20-%20Ochs,%20Pelachaud,%20Sadek%20-%20AAMAS%2008.pdf), [2](http://www.fer.unizg.hr/images/50009013/mtap_ac.pdf), [3](http://cgi2010.miralab.unige.ch/short/SP09/SP09.pdf), [4](http://www.deepdyve.com/lp/association-for-computing-machinery/design-an-empathic-virtual-human-to-encourage-and-persuade-learners-in-aC4P9ILuJ0), e especialmente [5](http://www.semaine-project.eu/) e [6](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2535294/You-look-different-3-avatar-software-mimics-facial-expressions-transform-magical-creature-Skype.html)). Eu creio que todo esse esforço significa que há um reconhecimento da importância da humanização da máquina nessa interação humano-computador.

**Concluindo...**

Chegando finalmente no assunto da pergunta sobre a utilização ou não de desculpas em uma mensagem, tudo leva a crer que esse uso não apenas é aceitável (ao menos em nosso contexto cultural - e provavelmente também para os japoneses! :)) como pode ser até mesmo necessário em certas condições. De todas as formas, não se trata simplesmente de se desculpar por uma falha, mas de amenizar a forma como uma informação é apresentada ou de tornar a interação mais empática e natural ao usuário humano. E creio que isso vale para qualquer forma de interação, seja ela apenas textual ou não.

Um cenário em que o uso de "desculpe" parece válido sob o julgo dos argumentos anteriores é no caso em que a condição do programa interrompe ou impede a utilização do produto (ou de parte significativa do produto) por parte do usuário. Um exemplo desse cenário é quando um usuário liga seu PlayStation para assistir à um filme no NetFlix, mas o sistema informa que está em manutenção. Parece socialmente apropriado se desculpar nesse caso, principalmente porque o impacto na experiência ("puxa, eu queria realmente assistir a esse filme agora...") é definitivamente grande, e talvez esse impacto possa ser amenizado por uma indicação de humildade e subjugação na interação que demonstre de alguma forma a preocupação do criador em relação ao mal-estar causado pela falta do produto.

Talvez as desculpas realmente não sejam necessárias ao informar que o usuário não tem acesso a determinado recurso, mas temo que ainda assim isso dependa do contexto de utilização. Para indicar a um usuário de um sistema corporativo (isto é, um sistema que ele é obrigado a utilizar por motivos de trabalho) que ele não tem acesso a determinado recurso, a falta das desculpas parece ser irrelevante porque provavelmente a tentativa de acesso inválida tratou-se de um equívoco honesto por parte humana e não altera necessariamente a sua experiência. Entretanto, na indicação de impossibilidade de acesso a um recurso em um sistema de entretenimento ou pessoal (isto é, algo que o usuário usa porque deseja, e que o faz para ter diversão ou por algum benefício pessoal) o uso de desculpas pode ser apropriado. Em verdade, nesse caso talvez seja até mesmo apropriado incluir interações adicionais do tipo "Você gostaria de ter acesso a esse recurso?".

EDIT:

Encontrei [essa thread no *User Experience*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31359/should-error-messages-apologize) que trata do mesmo assunto. A resposta aceita (e também com mais votos) concorda que o uso de "desculpas" é apropriado e muitas vezes necessário. Entre os diversos argumentos (aconselho a leitura da questão e suas respostas), há dois baseados em citações de estudos científicos cujos resultados apoiam uma estratégia cortês de se desculpar.

A primeira citação é ao artigo "[*The Effect of Apologetic Error Messages and Mood States on Computer Users’ Self-appraisal of Performance*](http://www.academia.edu/249090/The_Effect_Of_Apologetic_Error_Messages_And_Mood_States_On_Computer_Users_Self-Appraisal_Of_Performance)". A passagem que me parece relevante é essa (em tradução livre):

> [...] Quando os usuários encontraram problemas, o sistema proveu
>   certas mensagens de erro representando uma estratégia de cortesia
>   positiva (por exemplo, uma piada), uma negativa (por exemplo, uma
>   simples desculpa) e uma mensagem de erro mecânica (por exemplo, a
>   página está temporariamente indisponível). Os resultados do estudo
>   demonstram que os usuários que lidam com eventos sociais e expressões
>   de cortesia preferem significativamente mais receber mensagens
>   com desculpas do que mensagens mecânicas ou com piadas; também preferem
>   significativamente mais receber tais mensagens do que outras opções
>   menos corteses.

A segunda citação é tirada do artigo "[*Computer Apology: The Effect of the Apologetic Feedback on Users in Computerized Environment*](http://hci.metu.edu.tr/conference/icalt2005.pdf)". Novamente, o que parece relevante em tradução livre:

> [...] esse estudo mostra que quase todos os
>   participantes não consideraram as respostas (*feedbacks*) com desculpas
>   como algo estranho, sendo que 95% deles considerou tais respostas delicadas e
>   uma consideração ao seu bem-estar. Nesse aspecto, parece que os
>   participantes acham tão interessante perceber um comportamento
>   respeitoso (como um pedido de desculpas) quando encontram um erro
>   causado pela inabilidade do computador como achariam se encontrassem
>   um problema na interação com um humano. Esses resultados do estudo
>   indicam que a representação do estado afetivo de uma pessoa no projeto
>   de interface é muito importante na interação humano-computador porque as pessoas são
>   mais compreensivas ao ver aspectos emocionais na interface como
>   sensibilidade, respeito e sensação de humanidade. Assim, esses
>   resultados talvez sejam evidências para suportar que o uso de
>   expressões com desculpas em computadores pode fomentar a ideia de um
>   projeto realmente centrado no usuário.

Cabe notar que não necessariamente as desculpas são mais apropriadas do que humor. No estudo científico da primeira citação a orientação dos usuários foi previamente avaliada e é esperado que pessoas que vivem em contextos sociais mais corteses (talvez, por exemplo, atendentes de hotel) prefiram comportamentos similares nos sistemas com que interagem. De todas as formas, nota-se nas duas pesquisa que a questão crucial é a humanização com que os usuários tratam o sistema, que deve ser incluída no projeto da interação de uma forma ou de outra.

Comment: Você achou a fonte do bigown :) E parabéns pela resposta. Eu quando vi essa pergunta tinha sérias dúvidas se apareceria alguma boa resposta, e você provou que eu estava errado.

Comment: Quem é esperto, pode levar muita rep nesses casos, trazendo bom conteúdo. É só ficar atento. E você fez mais. Sua resposta está melhor que a original.

Comment: ... isso é quase um artigo. Publica, cara! Sério!

Comment: Nossa, respeitei o cara @LuizVieira

Comment: A pergunta foi boa, mas a resposta foi excelente. Parabéns.

Answer (score 69):

### Cuidado ao pedir desculpas em uma exceção

Se desculpar por um erro não levaria um usuário a maioria dos usuários a pensar "nossa que legal, ele sabe que o erro foi dele"; uma mensagem de erro onde o sistema admite um erro passa a imagem de que erros são tão constantes que ele admite através da mensagem.

Um cliente demasiadamente rigoroso poderia encarar com maus olhos um sistema que pede desculpas por um erro.

Exceções ao que eu falei acima existem? Claro! Mas eu só vejo acontecer com grandes empresas: Google, Yahoo, etc. Se seu projeto tem uma boa reputação no mercado e o nome da empresa for de peso você poderia utilizar a mensagem como desculpa até mesmo para dar a entender que: "meu sistema é tão difícil de dar erro que acabou acontecendo. desculpe".

### O que devemos avaliar ao exibir uma mensagem erro?

Existem diversos fatores que devemos pesar ao criar uma mensagem de erro:

1. Qual o nível do usuário? Se seu usuário incluir pessoas com pouca afinidade com a informática, não tem razão para utilizar termos técnicos ou mensagem complexas.
2. Qual a clareza da mensagem? Qualquer pessoa que ler a mensagem será capaz de entender o erro? Talvez foi um NullPointerException que estourou no código, ou então foi um SaldoInsuficienteException; independente do tipo de erro a mensagem está clara?
3. Sempre definir a próxima ação do usário. Qual será a próxima ação após o erro? Tentar novamente? Entrar em contato com o suporte? Realizar alguma ação (como preencher determinado input) para que o erro não aconteça mais?
4. Nunca exibir o erro técnico. Evite deixar que qualquer erro seja exibido ao usuário sem ser tratado. Se a linguagem fosse Java, por exemplo, você poderia criar um ExceptionHandler que trataria qualquer tipo de erro que acontecesse no sistema (seja um erro esperado ou não). O problema de exibir o erro técnico para o usuário é que um hacker poderia utilizar essa mensagem de erro para te atacar.

### Dicas para uma boa mensagem de erro

1. Se o seu cliente for alguém informal você poderia tentar algo engraçado. Alguns exemplos seriam: Twitter (a baleia), Google (que fala de macacos que trabalham lá), GIT (Que mostra um JEDI para página não encontrada) e assim vai.
2. Se o seu cliente for alguém formal, tome cuidado com o que será exibido. O ideal seria informar que um erro inesperado aconteceu. Se possível, coloque um botão onde o cliente poderia enviar um email detalhando o problema.

### Agradando ao cliente

Quando um cliente percebe que existe uma pré-disposição do projeto para agir em um caso de erro, ele fica mais satisfeito. Apenas é bom dar uma resposta rápida ao usuário, nem que seja um email automático até que o problema seja analisado.

Comment: Eu usaria "Infelizmente" no lugar de "Desculpe".

Answer (score 55):

O bom humor é uma tendência que vem ganhando força nesses casos, principalmente na web. Lojas de e-commerce, por exemplo, utilizam mensagens como:

> Ops! Pelo jeito nossas promoções fizeram sucesso, estamos trabalhando
> para aumentar nossa nuvem de servidores, dentro de alguns instantes
> pressione F5

Agora, se o sistema necessita de algo mais formal, o padrão é que seja informada a ocorrência de um erro e na sequência alguma orientação, como por exemplo:

> Um erro ocorreu, tente novamente em alguns instantes e caso ainda
> tenha problemas entre em contato com o setor de suporte

No caso da sua pergunta, seria uma situação em que a solicitação não pode ser processada, porém não por falha no sistema, boas práticas são informar o usuário, da forma menos rude possível, pedidos de desculpas nesses casos não são medidas cabíveis, ***pense que se o usuário não tem permissão para fazer determinada ação, é por que isso foi pré determinado***, alguns exemplos:

> - Sua solicitação não pode ser completada, solicite o auxílio do Administrador
> - Você não tem permissão para realizar esta ação

Answer (score 29):

Ao meu ver a pergunta já foi respondida com muitos pontos positivos e importantes na interação com o usuário.

Acho importante a classificação do sistema e definição do público-alvo para poder medir as características do feedback ao usuário.

### Trata-se de uma questão de usabilidade

Primeiro, considerando falha como um erro irrecuperável, diante desses equívocos acho necessário considerar o possível estado de espírito do usuário ao saber que sua tarefa não foi completada. Mesmo que não seja culpa da programação do sistema, é comum que usuários mais leigos ponham a culpa no mesmo. É dessa forma então que defendo o ponto onde deve-se educar os usuários com mensagens confortáveis livrando a cara do sistema de erros que estão fora de sua alçada. Como erro de conexão na Internet. Nesse caso a mensagem de "desculpe" ao meu ver não é bem-vinda, mas sim um "Oops, não criemos pânico. Parece que você está com problemas de internet...", claro dependendo da formalidade do seu público.

Segundo, exceções do próprio sistema devem oferecer um diálogo que demonstre ao usuário um controle total sobre a situação. Já que nesses pontos, o sistema deve ser capaz de recuperar-se da exceção lançada, ou fornecer um meio de que o usuário o faça, dependendo do tipo de Exceção.

### Em todos esses pontos temos 3 características

1. Que tipo de Sistema eu tenho e para qual público ele é destinado?
2. Isso tudo me parece muito formal? É bom não formalizar mais ainda as coisas com mensagens bruscas, pelo contrário, devemos suavizar a interação humano-computador.
3. Os níveis de mensagem, certamente devem acompanhar os níveis de usuários.

Answer (score 23):

Existem dois casos muito distintos ao meu ver:

- Exceções para o desenvolvedor
- Mensagens de erro para o usuário final

### Texto de Exceções

Acho que uma exceção deve sempre ser o mais explicativa quanto for possível, de forma a indicar o que causou, e possivelmente como corrigir o problema em que o código tropeçou... dessa forma, o desenvolvimento e a manutenção da aplicação ficam mais fáceis, aumentando portanto a qualidade do software como produto final.

### Mensagens de Erro

Mensagens de erro dependem do público alvo... hoje em dia há uma tendência bem humorada quando se trata de softwares para as grandes massas. Entretanto no mundo corporativo, o ideal mesmo é se manter sério e bem educado, mas não acho que se deva chegar ao ponto de pedir desculpas... isso me passa uma impressão ruim. Ao invés disso, seria muito melhor apresentar um telefone de contato, em e-mail, um link para abrir um ticket... seja lá o que for, mas visando uma solução. Uma mensagem proativa no sentido da solução é a melhor coisa a se fazer... obviamente que no meu ponto de vista.