# Melhores práticas UX para sinalização e usabilidade de formulários

Tags: ux

Hoje me deparei com um dado interessante: nos últimos 10 anos, [nosso período de atenção caiu de 12 para apenas 5 minutos](http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/attention-spans-have-dropped-from-12-minutes-to-5-seconds-how-social-media-is-ruining-our-minds-infographic/87484?red=st). Um dado que pode ser confirmado pelo crescente número de usuários de microblogs como o Twitter e a nossa predisposição a [não visualizar mais de 60 segundos de um vídeo no YouTube](http://www.businessinsider.com/2008/12/people-only-watch-web-videos-for-10-seconds-or-less-).

**Dúvida:** Fazendo relação a isso - já que as pessoas tendem a abandonar algo que lhes exija mais tempo e trabalho do que elas esperam, qual seria o melhor modo de implementar sinalização de estado em formulários, levando em consideração a conclusão rápida dos mesmos?

Para exemplificar minha dúvida vou mostrar o formulário de login em meu sistema, em seu estado inicial, optei por mostrar apenas as informações que achei realmente relevantes (omitindo informações de obrigatoriedade, etc), e posteriormente mostrando as informações do contexto.

[image: Estados de validação do formulário]
<sub>Estados de validação do formulário.</sub>

Abri meu sistema para feedback com **50 pessoas**, analisando os resultados vi que **19 pessoas acharam que o formulário tem falta de sinalização de obrigatoriedade e validação**. E o que me confunde, é que com outros formulários mais complexos do sistema (que seguem a mesma abordagem desse em questão) foram avaliados com boa usabilidade e sinalização.

Além disso, o que distingue um formulário limpo e com boa usabilidade de um que deixa de orientar o usuário?

Comment: Esse formulário específico foi avaliado desse jeito?! Se ainda fosse o formulário de cadastro eu entenderia, mas para fazer login você precisa do *seu* e-mail e da *sua* senha, nada menos que isso e nada diferente disso...

Comment: Uma li uma estória que é tida como verdadeira quando começou se introduzir pesquisas de opinião no Brasil e lançaram uma sopa, acho que era Campbell mas posso estar misturando as coisas, e a pesquisa mostrou que seria um sucesso. Lançaram e foi um fracasso. Aí a conclusão foi que brasileiro não sabe responder pesquisa. EU acho que quase ninguém sabe responder pesquisa, mas me parece que brasileiro é pior mesmo. Ele quer agradar o entrevistador, mesmo não tendo a menor ideia de como fazer isto, parece instintivo.

Comment: Estraga o intuito original tentando fazer o que ele acha que é o que uma "boa pessoa" faria. Tem também a estória do Windows Vista que não sei o quanto é verdadeira em que colocaram pessoas usando um Vista ligeiramente modificado no auge do ódio que as pessoas estavam tendo por ele. Perguntaram o que achavam desta nova versão e a maioria adorou. E tem várias estórias destas, vou parar nestas. Por isto eu sou um pouco crítico destes testes que pedem a opinião das pessoas. Prefiro testes que observam o comportamento das pessoas, que também tem lá suas limitações.

Comment: Acho até que o Luiz Viera conduz um estudo para captar o nível de diversão de jogadores. Algo que parece ser bem interessante.

Comment: Esse foi o formulário com pior avaliação na pesquisa, @mgibsonbr, mas o de cadastro (http://i.imgur.com/mfWLJi4.png) também obteve uma pontuação parecida, talvez estejam sentindo falta dos tradicionais `* Campo obrigatório`?

Comment: Eu concordo com o @mgibsonbr no sentido de que esse formulário é simples e não tem muita relação com engajamento como as referências que você passou (isto é, ninguém se interessa *por si só* em digitar usuário e senha). Então talvez eu não tenha entendido corretamente a pergunta... Sobre a sua pesquisa, pode dar mais detalhes sobre como foi conduzida? Principalmente, quem foi o público pesquisado? Se, por exemplo, foram em grande parte colegas programadores, eles podem ter sido induzidos a sentir falta da indicação de obrigatoriedade sem isso ter sido realmente um problema de usabilidade.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O seu exemplo não é exatamente um dos melhores porque, tal como já foi comentado, um formulário de login é suficientemente simples e padronizado ao ponto de que praticamente todo usuário já acostumado com serviços na Internet (Facebook, Gmail, etc) deve ser capaz de entender que **precisa** fornecer um nome de usuário e uma senha para ter acesso ao serviço.

Além disso, a sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Principalmente a respeito do que você quer dizer com "estado", já que você mesmo menciona que a informação de obrigatoriedade (o que parece ser a sua principal conclusão e o item que foi avaliado na sua pesquisa) foi omitida porque você a julga irrelevante.

De todas as formas, eu entendi que a sua pergunta é essencialmente sobre como implementar boa sinalização (de forma genérica) em formulários para auxiliar na Usabilidade, principalmente tendo em vista as suas citações a respeito do engajamento. Vou tentar bolar uma resposta nesse sentido.

### Usabilidade e Testes

Bom, primeiramente, usabilidade descreve o quão fácil é usar um produto (facilidade + usar -> usabilidade, eis dai a semântica da palavra). E por fácil pode-se entender muitas coisas, mas principalmente se a interação com o produto é eficaz e eficiente, útil/interessante para quem utiliza e ergonômica (não requer esforço além do necessário, não cansa, etc). Se você ainda não o fez, sugiro que leia mais sobre o assunto, talvez aqui mesmo no SOPT com as tags [usabilidade](/questions/tagged/usabilidade) e [ux](/questions/tagged/ux).

Você não forneceu os detalhes da sua pesquisa (mesmo após pedidos), mas se as pessoas entrevistadas sentiram falta da indicação de obrigatoriedade há potencialmente duas razões:

1. Elas usaram o seu formulário de login, não preencheram algum dos campos obrigatórios (no caso, usuário e/ou senha), clicaram em "Faça Login" e ficaram frustradas com a indicação de que esse esforço inicial foi inútil porque um ou mais campos eram obrigatórios.
2. Elas também são desenvolvedores e estão acostumados com o "padrão de indicar com asterísco os campos obrigatórios" (muito embora talvez nem entendam o porquê disso). Como não viram essa indicação no seu formulário, citaram-na como algo faltante.

O primeiro caso é o que se intenciona observar com um teste com usuários reais. Afinal, usuários não são garantidamente desenvolvedores. Eu acho pouco provável que tenha sido esse caso na sua pesquisa, porque esse formulário é muito simples e (como eu já mencionei) a grande maioria dos usuários já estão acostumados com o uso de sistemas que requerem login para saber que devem fornecer ambos os dados. A não ser, é claro, que seus usuários sejam pessoas totalmente inexperientes com o uso de computadores. Mas, nesse caso eu ficaria surpreso por eles terem entendido o que significa a palavra "login" e terem conseguido clicar no "botão"... :)

O segundo caso me parece mais provável. E ai, há um erro importante. Você não deve testar as suas aplicações com outros desenvolvedores (a não ser que o que você esteja construindo seja especificamente pra eles). Desenvolvedores irão essencialmente te oferecer respostas que você é capaz de observar sozinho, e por isso são de pouca ajuda. Os testes precisam ser feitos com os usuários reais ou com pessoas que sejam representativas desse grupo, pois só assim é possível perceber quais são as reais dificuldades de utilização com a interface.

### Aspectos Importantes no Seu Formulário

Tendo colocado os pontos de vista anteriores sobre os testes e validação, eu creio que posso oferecer algumas observações sobre o seu formulário atual de login. Ainda assim, elas são observações baseadas na minha experiência como projetista de interfaces, e podem não estar totalmente corretas. Elas servem como sugestões de *melhores práticas de design*, mas sua validade ou não depende realmente dos usuários no contexto do seu produto.

Mesmo que a usabilidade de um formulário não seja das melhores, os usuários podem já ser suficientemente experientes para ignorar tais problemas ou ter algum interesse em se esforçar mais do que precisariam. Isto é, em relação a engajamento que você cita (sugiro ler também a minha resposta [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56308/muitas-telas-ou-uma-tela-com-muitas-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es)), também depende da motivação para o uso. Um formulário de login péssimo (imagine algo realmente ruim de utilizar) poderia ser relevado por usuários interessados em jogar um espetacular jogo que vem depois dele (motivação intrínseca), ou por usuários que precisam acessar o site do banco para fazer uma transação financeira (motivação extrínseca).

Eis as minhas observações:

- "**Faça Login**" não é uma expressão comum da língua portuguesa. Ela talvez seja facilmente entendida por programadores ou por outros usuários que já tenham inferido ou se acostumado com seu significado depois de tantos usos por ai. Ainda assim, trata-se de um anglicismo de difícil tradução. Por isso que sistemas profissionais usam "Entrar" ou "Acessar" ao invés de *login* e "Registrar" ou "Cadastrar" ao invés de *signin* (veja o Facebook, por exemplo), simplesmente porque garantem um acesso mais amplo e fácil aos usuários comuns no nosso idioma. Você mesmo usa "faça o seu cadastro" ali embaixo.
- "**Não consegue acessar?**" é uma pergunta meramente retórica, e perguntas retórias são comumente confusas ou inúteis. Acredite, esse tipo de texto é algo que programadores usam muito. Aqui em São Paulo há um sistema de auto-atendimento para o pagamento de estacionamentos em shopping centers que faz a seguinte pergunta: "Cliente Porto tem desconto?", seguido de dois botões com "Sim" e "Não", para demandar se o cliente do estacionamento é cliente da seguradora (pois, em tese, ele teria um desconto no valor do estacionamento). Eu sempre rio muito ao ver essa frase porque penso: "Se eu acertar, o que eu ganho?". :) Piadas à parte, é fácil observar a confusão das pessoas utilizando esses quiosques quando chegam nesse ponto da interação. No seu caso, pode acontecer o mesmo. Essa pergunta é potencialmente confusa porque o usuário lê o texto e *não necessariamente entende* que no caso de dificuldades de acessar deve clicar ali. O texto não parece um link, tal como o "Faça o seu cadastro", e não diz claramente a ação esperada. Seria melhor formatar tal como um link (e manter esse padrão durante toda a interface) e usar o texto "Não consegue acessar? Clique aqui.".
- O **uso de cores** e **mensagens de erro** é sempre interessante principalmente porque eles adicionam informações relevantes à interação. As mensagens de erro devem ser informativas, [educadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2539/as-mensagens-de-erro-devem-se-desculpar), e indicarem apenas os campos com erro (se o usuário errou apenas a senha, exibir também a mensagem abaixo do campo do email vai seguramente deixá-lo confuso a respeito de onde o erro ocorreu). As cores também ajudam o usuário a identificar rapidamente onde está o erro, principalmente em formulários longos. Mas tal como nos links, é importante manter o padrão em toda a aplicação. No seu formulário não é claro o porquê dos campos ficarem verdes. Acredito que a intenção é só mostrar que o campo foi preenchido, mas isso parece ser desnecessário dada a óbvia indicação de que há texto nele. Além disso, as cores não devem ser a única ou a principal indicação do estado de erro, porque há pessoas que podem ter dificuldades em interpretá-las. Há diversos graus de daltonismo, por exemplo, então é mais interessante ter cores contrastantes do que apenas esteticamente agradáveis. O verde, além de provavelmente desnecessário, [pode ser confundido com o vermelho](http://gizmodo.uol.com.br/e-assim-que-um-daltonico-ve-o-mundo/) por pessoas com esse tipo de dificuldade.
- O **principal problema** (que seguramente tem relação com a indicação da obrigatoriedade, mas é mais importante do que ela sozinha) é a percepção de esforço desnecessário por parte do utilizador. Não é exatamente o caso do seu formulário de exemplo, mas seria em um formulário de cadastro onde o usuário cria a senha. Isto é, a informação de que a senha precisa ter entre 6 e 18 dígitos, e que precisa usar ao menos um número e um caractere especial, etc, etc, etc, deve ser clara desde o início da interação. Deixar para informar isso apenas após o usuário tentar entrar qualquer senha que ele desejar é muito frustrante. Por isso em formulários longos a indicação dos campos obrigatórios é especialmente importante, pois evita a frustração em ter que submeter os dados para descobrir o que é requerido aos poucos. Essa frustração é totalmente disruptiva naqueles casos em que tudo o que já foi digitado no formulário é completamente perdido após o clique em enviar porque um campo obrigatório não foi preenchido (quem nunca abandonou um site com raiva por causa disso pode se considerar um(a) sortudo(a)).

P.S.: O seu formulário de login tem também um potencial problema de segurança, já que ele diz claramente para qualquer um que tente um acesso que as senhas no seu sistema têm tamanho fixo entre 6 e 18 dígitos. Essa informação é desnecessária nesse contexto (seria importante apenas no contexto da criação da senha).

> Esta é a forma como os daltônicos com [protanopia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daltonismo#Tipos_de_daltonismo) (a forma mais comum
>   de daltonismo) devem enxergar o seu formulário.
>
> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>
> Fonte: [Color Blindness Check](http://www.etre.com/tools/colourblindsimulator/?imageid=d8804d4a1fb1dd4f3ed779a6af0ade52&condition=protanopia)

Comment: Sensacional! Nunca havia pensado sobre a questão de daltonismo ou outras deficiência na percepção de cores. Temos que tomar muito cuidado com certos projetos que tentam ser "clean" ou sutis demais e acabam sendo impeditivos para certos usuários.

Comment: Ótima resposta, Luiz Vieira. Ainda hoje edito minha pergunta colocando mais dados sobre a pesquisa citada e com outro `form`, mas sua resposta já sanou minhas dúvidas, obrigado.

Comment: Por nada. Só tome cuidado com a edição pra não deixar a pergunta ampla demais. Do jeito que ela está já há alguma amplitude. Eu deixei intencionalmente de lado a questão da "conclusão rápida" dos formulários, por exemplo, porque só isso já dá outra pergunta (e resposta).

Comment: Sou desenvolvedor web Jr e atualmente tenho me interessado cada vez mais pela interação que o usuários em meus produtos. Seu texto me esclareceu muitas duvidas e ainda trouxe alguns tópicos que eu não havia reparado, assim como nosso colega eu também utilizava o verde nos campos para indicar que estava tudo em ordem, mas nunca parei para pensar que isso pode prejudicar no caso de daltonismo. Muito Obrigado pela resposta!