# Placeholders deveriam conter exemplos ou descrições?

Tags: input, ux, placeholder

Estou construindo uma aplicação e em meus formulários os *placeholders* dos campos estão vazios pois ainda não decidi que critério vou utilizar para preenchê-los.

Em muitos sites e *apps* é comum encontrar dois tipos de *placeholders* para os campos em formulários:

- Os vazios;
- Os que apresentam a descrição do campo;
- Os que mostram um exemplo de como o campo deveria ser preenchido.

Um exemplo:

```html
<form>
  E-mail:<br>
  <input type="text"><br>
  E-mail<br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="you@example.com"><br>
  E-mail:<br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail">
</form>
```

No que tange à experiência do usuário, qual das opções deveria ser usada e o que justifica o seu uso?

<sub>Veja que não estou interessado na opinião pessoal de qual é o melhor. Estou procurando fatos com bases concretas que mostrem que a utilização de uma ou de outra opção promove a experiência fácil e útil dentro dos conceitos de usabilidade e de experiência do usuário.</sub>

Comment: Eu gosto de consultar as diretivas do Material para UX. No caso, ele fala que tanto faz o exemplo como a ação. https://material.io/guidelines/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-layout, tem um tópico sobre placeholder

Comment: Diria que *"vai depender"*, ainda sim para a maior parte dos lugares eu mantenho uma coisa em mente: *nada mais de descritivo que um bom exemplo* :D

Comment: Ao meu ver, esta pergunta é inteiramente semelhante à [As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/5878) e não entendo porquê deveria ser fechada.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Placeholders devem conter exemplos ou descrições?

Sempre que possível devem conter instruções, amigáveis e que educadamente, ajudem o usuário a entender como preencher os campos. **Usabilidade**, essa é palavra.

---

Já existe uma *thread* no [*User Experience*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/49191) — site da *Stack Exchange*, sobre as experiências relacionadas ao usuário, que busca razoavelmente tratar do mesmo assunto. Entretanto, a simples tradução dessa resposta não atenderia aos padrões de países latinos, assim como dito em "[As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/66203)":

> Primeiramente, há de se considerar que existem diferenças culturais significativas com relação ao ato de se desculpar [...]

E não somente o ato de se desculpar, mas até a forma de responder uma simples pergunta não se aplica à todas culturas.

---

Com base na minha pesquisa relacionada à *placeholders*, gostaria de compartilhar alguns pontos positivos e negativos, respectivamente:

#### Pontos positivos

- Na maioria dos navegadores, *placeholders* são exibidos até o momento em que o usuário digita a primeira letra;
- *Placeholders* ajudam expondo dicas/exemplos de como o campo deve ser preenchido.

#### Pontos negativos

- A memória de curto prazo do usuário não colabora em nada, então quando o usuário começa a digitar e o *placeholder* desaparece, o usuário fica perdido;
- Os usuários podem confundir um *placeholder*, com dados que foram preenchidos automaticamente pelo navegador;
- Em casos gerais, exceto quando se utiliza um *label flutuante*, o usuário não consegue verificar como e qual é o tipo de informação que ele deve preencher, causando mais problemas.

---

No Brasil (pelo menos), a grande maioria das pessoas, não costumam se preocupar com suas obrigações (e nem direitos). São poucas as pessoas que possuem interesse em se informar sobre um determinado assunto. E, essa "preguiça de pensar por si mesmo" acaba acarretando sérios problemas (olhe para situação política dos país). Pense então que, quanto mais você facilitar para o usuário, melhor será a experiência e menos problemas — é incrível a capacidade que o usuário tem de encontrar problemas.

Sendo assim, sugiro seguir o exemplo dessa outra [discussão do *User Experience*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/85053). Ela aborda o campo do tipo **senha**, e a resposta mais votada e aceita exemplifica três formas de utilização, bem como seus pontos fortes e fracos. Resumidamente:

- Usar um simples texto no *placeholder* do campo é a **pior opção**:

[image: Pior maneira de utilizar o placehoder]

Essa é uma opção terrível para o usuário. Basicamente, ele se sente tratado como uma máquina. Ele olha pro campo e recebe a ordem "*Senha*", o que não há nenhuma interação humanizada. Já, em uma das respostas relacionada à questão "mensagens de erro", existe um trecho muito interessante ao qual gostaria de destacar:

> Quando os usuários encontraram problemas, o sistema proveu certas mensagens de erro representando uma estratégia de cortesia positiva (por exemplo, uma piada), uma negativa (por exemplo, uma simples desculpa) e uma mensagem de erro mecânica (por exemplo, a página está temporariamente indisponível). Os resultados do estudo demonstram que os usuários que lidam com eventos sociais e expressões de cortesia preferem significativamente mais receber mensagens com desculpas do que mensagens mecânicas ou com piadas; também preferem significativamente mais receber tais mensagens do que outras opções menos corteses.

Entretanto, podemos utilizar um *label* acima do campo e em conjunto com o *placeholder*, descrever brevemente os requisitos do referido campo:

[image: Melhor uso do Placehoder]

Observe que você terá uma melhor apresentação e clareza no que é preciso ser feito. Lendo, você automaticamente entenderia: "Digite a senha, com pelo menos 6 caracteres".

E por último, **a melhor opção** mencionada na própria resposta: "mantenha todas informações fora do campo (***no-placeholder***)", juntamente com instruções humanizadas, logo abaixo do *label*:

[image: Melhor maneira de usar o Placehoder]

Estudos de *eye-tracking* mostram que os olhos do usuários são atraídos para campos que estejam vazios. Na pior das hipóteses, irão olhar o campo que está com *placeholder* e ignorá-lo acreditando que esteja preenchido.

---

Outro ponto que vale ressaltar é a humanização da interação máquina-usuário. Perceba que instruções "*básicas*", acabam soando ao usuário como sendo ríspidas. Quando você trabalha com seres humanos, é impossível agradar a todos, mas é importante sempre tentar, no mínimo, ser o mais educado o possível e trazer uma experiência agradável ao usuário.

[image: Form Polar]

O formulário acima (*user-friendly*), traz informações que se "*auto-completam*", tanto no *label* como no *placeholder* e trazem a experiência de ser um diálogo e não uma "*ordem* ao usuário".

É interessante que você procure uma abordagem nessa "*pegada*", sempre trazendo e mantendo as informações (como [neste exemplo](http://css-plus.com/examples/2011/09/userfriendly-input-placeholder/)).

---

Por fim, veja a diferença entre os *inputs* citados na pergunta e um formulário com a técnica do *label* flutuante que encontrei em um [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jb013rqe/3/):

```html
<form>
  E-mail:<br>
  <input type="text"><br>
  E-mail<br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="you@example.com"><br>
  E-mail:<br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail">
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {
$(".formStyle7 .input-group input").blur(function() {

    var text_val = $(this).val();
    if (text_val === "") {
        $(this).removeClass('has-value');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('has-value');
    }
});
});
```

```css
.formStyle7 {
display: block;
height: 750px;
width: 500px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: none;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: rgb(128, 128, 128) .1px .1px 5px, rgb(128, 128, 128) -.1px -.1px 5px;
margin: 30px auto;
}

input {
background: none;
border: 1px solid #21a1e1;
margin: 15px;
display: inline-block;
height: 30px;
width: 455px;
}

input:focus,
input:active {
outline: none;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"] {
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b3c1cc;
}

.input-group {
position: relative;
}

.input-group label {
position: absolute;
left: 15px;
top: 30px;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 18px;
color: #999;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
pointer-events: none;
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.input-group input:focus+label,
.input-group input.has-value+label {
top: 13px;
font-size: 12px;
color: #aaa;
}

.clearFix {
clear: both;
}

header {
height: 40px;
width: 500px;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
color: #b3c1cc;
float: left;
margin: 25px 10px 0px 15px;
}

p {
height: 40px;
width: 500px;
font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
color: #b3c1cc;
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-top: -5px;
}

.formContainer {
margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<form class="formStyle7">
    <header>
        Form
    </header>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
    <div class="formContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text">
            <label>First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text">
            <label>Last Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email">
            <label>Email Address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text">
            <label>Contact Number</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text">
            <label>Date for Workshop</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text">
            <label>Time for Workshop</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text">
            <label>Location for Workshop</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fornecer um exemplo da entrada necessária ajuda um usuário a entender o campo. No entanto, incorporar o exemplo como texto de espaço reservado causa problemas, incluindo: perca do foco, confusão quanto ao que foi inserido e redução do uso do `input`. Como alternativa, o exemplo de texto pode ser colocado abaixo do campo de entrada.

O texto do `placeholder` é frequentemente empregado para fornecer mais informações sobre o que é necessário para completar um campo. Esta prática é ruim pelas mesmas razões declaradas anteriormente e ainda mais duvidosa devido à quantidade de texto usado. Os designers e desenvolvedores equivocados muitas vezes cometem o erro de usar um espaço reservado para comunicar mensagens longas.

Veja os inputs dos seguintes sites:

- Input de Pesquisa **StackOverflow**: Mais informações
- Input de Login **Hotmail**: Mais Informações
- Input login **Gmail**: Mais Informações
- Input de cadastro **Hotmail**: Exemplo

Ao que parece, isso **depende muito**. No entanto, costuma ser mais utilizado o `placeholder` contendo maiores detalhes, não exemplos.

**Fonte: https://uxdesign.cc/alternatives-to-placeholder-text-13f430abc56f**