# Escrever software em 1ª ou 3ª pessoa?

Tags: ux

Estou criando um software em C# e gostaria de saber se devo escrever ele em 1ª ou 3ª pessoa. Lembro-me que uma vez meu professor de lógica de programação chegou a comentar sobre isso (que softwares deveriam ser em 3ª pessoa, não me lembro ao certo, pois nem sempre quem está digitando o login e senha por exemplo é o usuário dono da conta)!

Por exemplo, devo escrever **ESQUECEU A SENHA?** ou **ESQUECEU A SUA SENHA?** ou **ESQUECI A MINHA SENHA?**

Comment: alguns sites usam também `Esqueci a senha` o que acho mais correto pois independe de se tratar do dono ou não. Mas isso pode não funcionar caso não seja o dono porque se clicar ai pode ser que seja enviado um procedimento no mail do dono e o ze que está tentando logar não obterá exito.

Comment: Relacioanda: [As mensagens de erro devem se desculpar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2539/91)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 18):

Não tem um padrão que podemos considerar como universal. Como todo aspecto de UX temos que analisar quem é o usuário, o que ele espera, porque um faz mais sentido que o outro, e isto inclui analisar a plataforma que estão usando, já que fazer algo diferente o que é "normal" será menos intuitivo.

O [guia da Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/text-style-tone?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) diz que deve usar a segunda pessoa para falar com o usuário, e me parece o mais adequado mesmo, se você vai dizer para ele o que fazer, chame ele diretamente, e isto é a 2a. pessoa.

E o guia diz para usar a primeira pessoa quando está pedindo para o usuário indicar o que quer que o software faça. Nada estranho, assim se estabelece uma conversação. De forma geral acho isto um pouco confuso na maioria das situações.

Dizem para não usar a terceira pessoa que é muito formal, ou até meio esquizofrênico :). A não ser que esteja se referindo a uma terceira mesmo pessoa mesmo, mais isso é raro.

Algo que eu estava pensando e revisando minha resposta, é que o uso do possessivo pode ser uma boa. Isso é a terceira pessoa e cabe em alguns contextos, cito abaixo caso onde a terceira pessoa não é nem o computador, nem o usuário. Pode até usar a 3a. pessoa para o usuário se for uma lista de posses de vários usuários. Aí fica padronizado. Ou pode diferenciar o usuário de propósito, até para destacar o que ele é dele mesmo, aí a 1a. pessoa só no usuário atual pode ser útil.

Você, como usuário, quer mandar ou ser mandado? Aí a primeira pessoa faz mais sentido.

Muitas vezes é melhor deixar um tom neutro:

> Eu não posso fazer esta operação por causa de...
>
> Você não pode fazer esta operação por causa de...
>
> Xablau não pode fazer esta operação por causa de... / O usuário não pode fazer esta operação por causa de...
>
> Esta operação não pode ser realizada por causa de...

Qual você acha melhor? Acusar o usuário, assumir a culpa, fazer de conta que é outra pessoa, mesmo não sendo, ou apenas informar?

Talvez a primeira pessoa seja interessante para um botão com uma ação que deve ser feita em seu nome, a neutralidade quando não é uma ação, é apenas um objeto, algo que existe, e a segunda pessoa quando é uma instrução direta para você. O que é melhor?

> Eu preciso ser informado do que fazer
>
> Você deve me dizer o que fazer
>
> Xablau deve me informar o que fazer / O usuário deve me informar o que fazer
>
> Me informe o que fazer

ou

```
Meus Documentos
Seus Documentos
Documentos do Xablau / Documentos do usuário
Documentos
```

Será que precisa do pronome mesmo? Talvez, quando existam várias "pessoas" envolvidas.

Escolha:

<kbd>Emita meu certificado</kbd>

<kbd>Emita seu certificado</kbd>

<kbd>Emita certificado do Xablau</kbd> / <kbd>Emita certificado do usuário</kbd>

<kbd>Emita o certificado</kbd>

Uma variação:

<kbd>Emito o certificado</kbd>

<kbd>Emita o certificado</kbd>

<kbd>Emitir o certificado</kbd>

<kbd>Emissão do certificado</kbd>

Sugiro ler essa [excelente resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2709/101) para entender melhor o contexto.

O [guia do quase finado Yahoo!](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307203709/https://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/social/core/yourvmy.html) detalha melhor quando usar um ou outro, mas não dá a opção da neutralidade que eu acho melhor.

Esta resposta está baseada em [respostas do User Experience da SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/4348/1490). Há até discussão se a Microsoft segue ou não seu próprio guia. Então quando envolve língua entramos em um campo subjetivo.

Há indicações em [outras respostas quando a 3a. pessoa pode ser usada, desde que não pelo pronome](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/24612/1490). Se usarmos o nome da pessoa evitamos a decisão de qual pronome usar.

Mais uma escolha, em um ERP (você é o usuário responsável pelo faturamento da empresa):

```
Minhas Notas Fiscais
Suas Notas Fiscais
Notas Fiscais da empresa
Notas Fiscais
```

Também aprendemos que deve ser consistente, a não ser que tenha um motivo forte para mudar, o que ainda deixaria consistente.

UX é algo no nosso escopo e não tem como falar nela sem algum grau de subjetividade. Desenvolvedores nunca serão bons de UX, podem ser razoáveis. Claro que desconsidero os maus profissionais, de dev ou de UX, esses serão ruins sempre. Para o básico podemos cuidar da UX, para uma UX forte é melhor deixar com especialistas de grande competência. Se usar um especialista, tem que ficar muito bom, o que não vejo acontecendo muito.

Temos guias, mas não uma resposta definitiva.

[Veja mais em um site especializado](http://www.designingsocialinterfaces.com/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Complementando um pouco da resposta do amigo @Maniero, temos guias mas não uma resposta definitiva, porque o texto necessário variar de acordo com o requisito. Aproveitando o exemplo do mesmo. Vamos dizer que o usuário do sistema vai emitir o certificado de uma terceira pessoa, usaremos "Emitir usuario de" + x.pessoa (Emitir certificado de fulano), digamos que você está fazendo um curso e precisa emitir o seu certificado, vai referir a se mesmo.  (Emitir o meu certificado). Então não pode existir uma regra universal para isso

Comment: @gabrielfalieri exatamente